# gridbags not sizing equally

Tags: java, jdeveloper

I have a problem with gridbags ( i will post the code at the end)

the gridbag has several panels, including 2 scroll panels.

The problem occours when the user tries to resize the form.

at first it sizes correctly, with all the panels stretching correctly, until it reaches the point that the upper scollpane stretches to the point that the scroll bar disapears, at which point the lower scroll pan drops in size, leaving a large gap between the top scroll pane and the buttons in the middle

looking in design view ( JDEV) it all looks fine, I can't see anything that would be causing this.  I have tried putting the MainPanel onto another Panel as a base, which made no difference.

If any body has any ideas, I would be welcome to hear them. I think it has gotten to the point that I cant see the trees for the wood

```
this.getContentPane().setLayout(borderLayout1);

this.getContentPane().add(MainPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);


FieldPanel.setLayout(gridBagLayout2);
FormPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(EtchedBorder.LOWERED));
MainPanel.setLayout(gridBagLayout1);
ButtonPanel.setLayout(gridBagLayout3);
BottomPanel.setLayout(gridBagLayout5);
TopPanel.setLayout(gridBagLayout6);
WorkflowButtonPanel.setLayout(gridBagLayout4);
SQLScrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 80));
SQLScrollPane.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(50, 80));
WorkflowTable.setName("WorkFlowRulesWorkFlowTable");
WorkflowScrollPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("WorkFlow"));
FieldPanel.add(WorkFlowRulesIDLabel, new GridBagConstraints(0, 0, 1, 1, 0.0, 0.0, GridBagConstraints.WEST, GridBagConstraints.NONE, new Insets(2, 2, 3, 3), 0, 0));


TopPanel.add(FieldPanel, new GridBagConstraints(0, 0, 1, 1, 1.0, 1.0, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.BOTH, new Insets(2, 2, 3, 3), 0, 0));
WorkflowScrollPane.getViewport().add(WorkflowTable, null);
TopPanel.add(WorkflowScrollPane, new GridBagConstraints(0, 1, 1, 1, 1.0, 1.0, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.BOTH, new Insets(0, 0, 2, 0), 0, 0));

BottomPanel.add(WorkflowButtonPanel, new GridBagConstraints(0, 1, 1, 1, 1.0, 0.0, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL, new Insets(4, 2, 3, 3), 0, 0));
SQLScrollPane.getViewport().add(SQLTextArea, null);
BottomPanel.add(SQLScrollPane, new GridBagConstraints(0, 2, 1, 1, 1.0, 2.0, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.BOTH, new Insets(1, 0, 0, 0), 0, 140));

MainPanel.add(TopPanel, new GridBagConstraints(0, 0, 1, 1, 1.0, 1.0, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.BOTH, new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0), 0, 0));
MainPanel.add(BottomPanel, new GridBagConstraints(0, 1, 1, 1, 1.0, 1.0, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.BOTH, new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0), 0, 0));
MainPanel.add(ButtonPanel, new GridBagConstraints(0, 2, 1, 1, 1.0, 0.0, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL, new Insets(4, 2, 3, 3), 0, 0));

FieldPanel.add(WorkFlowRulesIDField, new GridBagConstraints(1, 0, 1, 1, 1.0, 1.0, GridBagConstraints.WEST, GridBagConstraints.NONE, new Insets(2, 2, 3, 3), 0, 0));
FieldPanel.add(UserRefLabel, new GridBagConstraints(0, 1, 1, 1, 1.0, 1.0, GridBagConstraints.WEST, GridBagConstraints.NONE, new Insets(2, 2, 3, 3), 0, 0));
FieldPanel.add(UserRefField, new GridBagConstraints(1, 1, 1, 1, 1.0, 1.0, GridBagConstraints.WEST, GridBagConstraints.NONE, new Insets(2, 2, 3, 3), 0, 0));
FieldPanel.add(ExtRefLabel, new GridBagConstraints(0, 2, 1, 1, 1.0, 1.0, GridBagConstraints.WEST, GridBagConstraints.NONE, new Insets(2, 2, 3, 3), 0, 0));
FieldPanel.add(ExtRefField, new GridBagConstraints(1, 2, 1, 1, 1.0, 1.0, GridBagConstraints.WEST, GridBagConstraints.NONE, new Insets(2, 2, 3, 3), 0, 0));
FieldPanel.add(DescriptionLabel, new GridBagConstraints(0, 3, 1, 1, 1.0, 1.0, GridBagConstraints.WEST, GridBagConstraints.NONE, new Insets(2, 2, 3, 3), 0, 0));
FieldPanel.add(DescriptionField, new GridBagConstraints(1, 3, 3, 1, 1.0, 1.0, GridBagConstraints.WEST, GridBagConstraints.NONE, new Insets(2, 2, 3, 3), 0, 0));
FieldPanel.add(DescriptionLabel2, new GridBagConstraints(0, 4, 1, 1, 1.0, 1.0, GridBagConstraints.WEST, GridBagConstraints.NONE, new Insets(2, 2, 3, 3), 0, 0));
FieldPanel.add(DescriptionField2, new GridBagConstraints(1, 4, 3, 1, 1.0, 1.0, GridBagConstraints.WEST, GridBagConstraints.NONE, new Insets(2, 2, 3, 3), 0, 0));
FieldPanel.add(PriorityLevelLabel, new GridBagConstraints(0, 5, 1, 1, 1.0, 1.0, GridBagConstraints.WEST, GridBagConstraints.NONE, new Insets(2, 2, 3, 3), 0, 0));
FieldPanel.add(PriorityLevelField, new GridBagConstraints(1, 5, 3, 1, 1.0, 1.0, GridBagConstraints.WEST, GridBagConstraints.NONE, new Insets(2, 2, 3, 3), 0, 0));
FieldPanel.add(StatusFlagLabel, new GridBagConstraints(0, 6, 1, 1, 1.0, 1.0, GridBagConstraints.WEST, GridBagConstraints.NONE, new Insets(2, 2, 3, 3), 0, 0));
FieldPanel.add(StatusFlagComboBox, new GridBagConstraints(1, 6, 3, 1, 1.0, 1.0, GridBagConstraints.WEST, GridBagConstraints.NONE, new Insets(2, 2, 3, 3), 0, 0));

ButtonPanel.add(DestinationWorkflowLabel, new GridBagConstraints(0, 0, 1, 1, 1.0, 1.0, GridBagConstraints.WEST, GridBagConstraints.NONE, new Insets(2, 2, 3, 3), 0, 0));
ButtonPanel.add(DestinationWorkflowComboBox, new GridBagConstraints(1, 0, 1, 1, 1.0, 1.0, GridBagConstraints.WEST, GridBagConstraints.NONE, new Insets(2, 2, 3, 3), 0, 0));
ButtonPanel.add(SaveButton, new GridBagConstraints(0, 1, 1, 1, 1.0, 1.0, GridBagConstraints.SOUTHWEST, GridBagConstraints.NONE, new Insets(2, 2, 3, 3), 0, 0));
ButtonPanel.add(CancelButton, new GridBagConstraints(2, 1, 1, 1, 1.0, 1.0, GridBagConstraints.SOUTHEAST, GridBagConstraints.NONE, new Insets(2, 2, 3, 3), 0, 0));
ButtonPanel.add(TestButton, new GridBagConstraints(1, 1, 1, 1, 1.0, 1.0, GridBagConstraints.SOUTH, GridBagConstraints.NONE, new Insets(2, 2, 3, 3), 0, 0));

WorkflowButtonPanel.add(AddButton, new GridBagConstraints(0, 1, 1, 1, 1.0, 1.0, GridBagConstraints.SOUTHWEST, GridBagConstraints.NONE, new Insets(2, 2, 3, 3), 0, 0));
WorkflowButtonPanel.add(DeleteButton, new GridBagConstraints(2, 1, 1, 1, 1.0, 1.0, GridBagConstraints.SOUTHEAST, GridBagConstraints.NONE, new Insets(2, 2, 3, 3), 0, 0));
this.getContentPane().add(MainPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Comment: Do you have a mockup of what it should look like?

Comment: Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character.

Comment: perhaps not, but that doesn't have any impact on the form not sizing correctly